# Bug "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." when use Update-Database in Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm newbie about Asp.net core, I have an assignment about creating a create,edit,delete,detail Users in a table on database page. and I met mine as the title says, I really don't know what to do to fix it

This is my programs.cs file

```
using EditUserRazor.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EditUserRazor.Models;


namespace EditUserRazor {
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

            //DI
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseRouting();

                app.UseAuthorization();

                app.MapRazorPages();

                app.Run();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is my appsetting.json file

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefautConnection": "server=LENOVO_NOV\\MSSQLEXPRESS;database=KiemTra2;integrated security=true;trustservercertificate=true"
  }
}
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: Did you actually check that the connection string name you're specifying in your C# code exists in your config file? Did you really look at it closely?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string name used inside your codes(DefaultConnection) if different than you set inside the appsetting.json(DefautConnection).

I suggest you modify the config like below:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=LENOVO_NOV\\MSSQLEXPRESS;database=KiemTra2;integrated security=true;trustservercertificate=true"
  }
```